# How to pass a value in a new window, which will be opened in small size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Basically what i am looking for is 2 things:

1. Show a value to users in hyperlink and a value will be there too, which will be hidden.

& when user clicks on the link:

2. A new window will open, which will be smaller in size and show the hidden value which was associated with the hyperlink.

How is this possible?

---

Here is what i got so far:

** By using hyperlink:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('comments.php', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250 , left=300 , top=150'); return false;">
    click
 </a>
```

**the problem here is- how am i going to set the hidden value to pass to the new window & how am i going to receive it in new window?**

** By using a button, which i can style to look like link

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="comments.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="xx" value="a1"/>
          <input type="submit" name="whatever" value="1" id="hyperlink-style-button" onclick="window.open('comments.php', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250 , left=300 , top=150'); return false;" />
   </form>
```

**here i can put hidden value and receive it in new window but how am i going to make the new window small size onload? i have tried below method but doesnt work:**

```
<body onload="window.resizeTo(200,200)">
```

I dont want to use Get method, as the value should be secret to users.

Comment: Then you should use cookies. try $.cookies plugin

Comment: i tried that too using session. But as the values will be created dynamically , so how am going to create dynamic names for sessions and receive them in new window with the same names?

Comment: Cookies are deffirent a bit from Sessions. sessions are created at server, cookies are created on client side. try this link: https://www.google.co.il/url?url=https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0CCQQFjABahUKEwjm9MaBtZfHAhXhFNsKHYY5CUQ&sig2=RMBXKNPrTPeWWjNLwNYHNQ&usg=AFQjCNHtdfZrFFApbNhgeR_Uac9rON5R1A